# GCP API Client Libraries Java Examples - com.google.api.services.deploymentmanager.DeploymentManager

Tags: java, api, google-cloud-platform, client, google-deployment-manager

I am looking to automate the provisioning of google cloud resources using Deployment Manager. Only I want to use the JAVA API library instead of gcloud.

Specifically need to provision the following components using DeploymentManager.

1. Cloud SQL - MSSQL
2. Cloud Run Service
3. VPC Network with the Connector to be used to connect Cloud Run to the Cloud SQL.

I think `com.google.api.services.deploymentmanager.DeploymentManager` is the starting point but I am not very sure.

This is what I have so far

```
        Builder builder = new Builder(
                com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(),
                new com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory(), null);
        builder.setApplicationName("spatial-cat-319209");
        builder.setDeploymentManagerRequestInitializer(new DeploymentManagerRequestInitializer());
        DeploymentManager deploymentManager = builder.build();

        deploymentManager.deployments().list("spatial-cat-319209").entrySet().stream().forEach(entry -> {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " = " + entry.getValue());
        });
        
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"));
        System.out.println(System.getenv("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"));
        
        deploymentManager.deployments().list("spatial-cat-319209").execute();
```

I get the following error in the last line:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
GET https://deploymentmanager.googleapis.com/deploymentmanager/v2/projects/spatial-cat-319209/global/deployments
{
  "code": 401,
  "errors": [
    {
      "domain": "global",
      "location": "Authorization",
      "locationType": "header",
      "message": "Login Required.",
      "reason": "required"
    }
  ],
  "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
  "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:146)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:118)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:37)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:428)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1111)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:514)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:455)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:565)
```

I do have the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS pointing to a file that contains the service account key (generated using `gcloud auth application-default login` command)

Any insights would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it looks like I have got it working with the code below.

I have demonstrated how to use gcloud command using processbuilder as well as the DeploymentManager API. I had to use GoogleCredentials to read the service-account-key-file and pass that to the HttpCredentialsAdapter.

It was very hard to locate but [this guide](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-java-client/oauth-2.0.html) came in handy. Posting a link as reference for someone who stumbles by later.

Let me know if this can be done in a better way.

```
        GoogleCredentials googleCredentials = GoogleCredentials
                .fromStream(new FileInputStream(System.getenv("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS")));
        HttpRequestInitializer httpRequestInitializer = new HttpCredentialsAdapter(googleCredentials);

        Builder builder = new Builder(
                com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(),
                com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), httpRequestInitializer);
        builder.setApplicationName("spatial-cat-319209");
        builder.setDeploymentManagerRequestInitializer(new DeploymentManagerRequestInitializer());
        DeploymentManager deploymentManager = builder.build();

        deploymentManager.deployments().list("spatial-cat-319209").entrySet().stream().forEach(entry -> {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " = " + entry.getValue());
        });

        System.out.println(System.getProperty("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"));
        System.out.println(System.getenv("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"));
        System.out.println("Listing deployments in project using gcloud command ...");
        // Runtime.getRuntime().exec("gcloud deployment-manager deployments list");
        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
        Process process = processBuilder.command("powershell", "gcloud", "deployment-manager", "deployments", "list")
                .start();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader rdr = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line = "";
        while ((line = rdr.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }

        isr = new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream());
        rdr = new BufferedReader(isr);
        while ((line = rdr.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        int rc = process.waitFor(); // Wait for the process to complete
        System.out.println("Return Code = " + rc);

        System.out.println("Listing deployments in project using DeploymentManager API...");

        DeploymentsListResponse deploymentsListResponse = deploymentManager.deployments().list("spatial-cat-319209")
                .execute();

        System.out.println("Number of deployments = " + deploymentsListResponse.size());
        deploymentsListResponse.forEach((depl, a) -> System.out.println(depl + " - " + a));

        System.out.println("Done");
```